# Join based on a condition of another column

Tags: r, merge, conditional-statements

So I want to join df_1 to df_2 based on id:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5))


df_2<- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5),name=c("a","a1","b","c","c2","d","d1","e","e1","e2","e3"),status=c("IN","OUT","OUT","PENDING","OUT","OUT","REFER","IN","OUT","REFER","OUT"))
```

and this is what my resulting dataset should look like:

```
df_merge<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5),name=c("a","b","c","d1","e"))
```

So I want to merge the name associated with `"IN"` and if that's not available then the name associated with `"PENDING"`, and after that it should be `"REFER"`, if none of these are there then match the id with the status of `"OUT"`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do a join, then `arrange` by 'id' and `factor` converted 'status' with `levels` in the specified order, grouped by 'id', get the first row with `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df_2, df_1) %>% 
  arrange(id, factor(status, levels = c('IN', 'PENDING', 'REFER', 'OUT'))) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-status)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#     id name 
#  <dbl> <fct>
#1     1 a    
#2     2 b    
#3     3 c    
#4     4 d1   
#5     5 e
```

---

It the 'df_1' is duplicated, then do the `left_join` with the `distinct` rows, later do a `right_join`

```
df_1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5)) 
left_join(df_2, distinct(df_1)) %>% 
    arrange(id, factor(status, levels = c('IN', 'PENDING', 'REFER', 'OUT'))) %>%  
    group_by(id) %>%
    slice(1) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-status)  %>%
    right_join(df_1)
# A tibble: 7 x 2
#     id name 
#* <dbl> <fct>
#1     1 a    
#2     1 a    
#3     2 b    
#4     3 c    
#5     4 d1   
#6     5 e    
#7     5 e
```

Or we can have a `list` column`or`nest`the 'id' and the`unnest`

```
library(tidyr)
df_1 %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    nest %>%
    right_join(df_2) %>%
    arrange(id, factor(status, levels = c('IN', 'PENDING', 'REFER', 'OUT'))) %>%   
    group_by(id) %>%
    slice(1) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-status) %>% 
    unnest
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_2)[df_1,  .(name = name[order(match(status,
      c('IN', 'PENDING', 'REFER', 'OUT')))[1]]), on = .(id), by = .EACHI]
#   id name
#1:  1    a
#2:  2    b
#3:  3    c
#4:  4   d1
#5:  5    e
```

---

Or a `base R` option is to first `order` the 'df_2' dataset, and then extract the elements of 'name' based on `duplicated` elements in 'id'

```
df_2n <- df_2[order(df_2$id, factor(df_2$status, levels = c('IN', 'PENDING', 'REFER', 'OUT'))),] 
df_1$name <-  df_2n$name[!duplicated(df_2$id)]
```

Comment: Thank you, you always have really good solutions. Just one question, what if I have a status that I didn't reflect in df_2, would I have to include that in the levels statement as well? For example, I have "Not found".

Comment: and also what if I have multiple rows per ID? for example, I have df_1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5))

Comment: @Mel you can use a condition `if/else` to create 'Not found' if none of the expected levels are not found in a group.  If youu have multiple rows per ID, cannot use `join` because it is not clear which row to match.  In that case, the logic should change. and it depends on how you want to make the logic

Comment: @Mel For the new dataset what would be the expected?  Here, it is not clear

Comment: the logic remains the same but I don't want to have one row per id. df_merge<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5),name=c("a","a","b","c","d1","e","e"))

Comment: @Mel so, you are still taking the first match, right

Comment: Yes, I'm taking the match with "IN" then "PENDING", "REFER", and lastly "OUT"

Comment: @Mel For the question youu raised earlier, I would first convert the 'status' column in 'df_2' with `ifelse` (assuming character classs) `ifelse(df_2$status %in% lvls, df_2$status, "Not Found"))`, then speciy `Not found` aslo in 'lvls' as the last entry in `levels` and apply the function